# Can I create Heroku Scheduler jobs via the CLI or other non-web UI method?

Tags: heroku, scheduler, cron-task

I'm working on a project which uses Heroku's '[Deploy to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button)' button to allow people to quickly configure and deploy an app. The app includes a recurring task, and I would like to use Heroku's free 'Scheduler' add-on to run it every day. Ideally I would like the 'setup' task that runs on deploy to create a job in the scheduler, so that the user deploying the app doesn't have to do it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, this is not possible using existing solutions.

I just created a new add-on, https://schedulerctl.com

Schedulerctl enables you to create and manage your Heroku Scheduler jobs using a REST API or the Heroku CLI.

These interfaces allow you to programatically combine Heroku Scheduler with other services like your Heroku button.